# How to read/get Virtual machine background processes using Kusto LOg query , Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-data-explorer, kql

I hope you all are doing great.

I'd like to How to read/get Virtual machine background processes using Kusto Log query on Azure Monitor log analytics process.

e.g. As shown in below screen shot:
[image]

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the perf counters for the process and you need to get the Process Names out of it by querying the perf table.

You can add the perf counter Process(*)\% Processor Time. By going to Log Analytics instance -> Advanced Settings -> Windows Performance Counters. Then query these performance counters as below.

Perf
| where ObjectName ==  "Process" 
| where  CounterName contains "Processor Time"
| summarize makelist(InstanceName) by   Computer

And other alternate way is by using the service map feature refer this , you can query ServiceMapProcess_CL table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-log-search .

Let me know if this answers.

Comment: Thanks Arun for your reply, i already know whatever you have advised above.it is through poratal but my concern is to enable windows event log through ARM template and how can i get details about the windows process running on that VM. I hope you get it now.

Comment: Still not clear. If you want to fetch it from Kusto then you need to insert perfmon/service map  data to log analytics Kusto or your Kusto cluster and then query out. Also perf counters can be enabled through ARM call as well. If you don't want a  Kusto approach then consider Powershell approach. You can use Azure run commands as well and get to the server.